# Why StrogLoop doesn't start the app with "$ slc start"?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

In all their tutorial [Getting started with LoopBack](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Getting+started+with+LoopBack) they start the app with `$ slc start`. I follow the tutorial step by step but my app doesn't start with `$ slc start`. I mean, the server `localhost:3000` isn't started with the command. However, it starts with `$ slc run`. Why it happens? Why `$ slc start` doesn't work but they use it all over?

Here is an output when I run `$ slc start` which doesn't work. The "page is not available":

```
C:\Users\user\sbox\strongloop\hello>slc start .
App `.` started under local process manager.
  View the status:  slc ctl status
  View the logs:    slc ctl log-dump
  More options:     slc ctl -h
```

And when I check the status, it says that it is stopped for some reason:

```
C:\Users\user\sbox\strongloop\hello>slc ctl status
manager:
  pid:                4764
  port:               8701
  base:               C:\Users\user\.strong-pm
current:
  status:             stopped
  link:               C:\Users\user\sbox\strongloop\hello
  current:            hello
  branch:             local-directory
  worker count:       0
```

And here is the output of `$ slc run .` that works, that starts the server:

```
C:\Users\user\sbox\strongloop\hi>slc run .
INFO strong-agent API key not found, StrongOps dashboard reporting disabled.
Generate configuration with:
    npm install -g strongloop
    slc strongops
See http://docs.strongloop.com/strong-agent for more information.
supervisor running without clustering (unsupervised)
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000/
Models created:
 [ { name: 'Bel Cafe', city: 'Vancouver', id: 1 },
  { name: 'Three Bees Coffee House', city: 'San Mateo', id: 2 },
  { name: 'Caffe Artigiano', city: 'Vancouver', id: 3 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`slc start` is used to start apps under process manager. We recommend using `node .` to start applications (`slc run` is an alias for `node .` anyways). I've asked our docs guy to update all references accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

We actually changed the LoopBack docs to start apps with `node .` everywhere instead of `slc start`.  Using `node .` is more appropriate for development on a local system because it gives you immediate feedback, error traces, etc.   Apparently we made this change right after the OP.

Using `slc start` is useful to configure clustering and run the app under control of Str

Rand